# How to pre-compile jsp file in RAD 8.0?

Tags: websphere, rad

We are using RAD 8.0 as IDE and we want to pre-compile jsp while building the project itself. This feature can be found in RAD 7.0 at:

```
Window > Preferences > Web Tools > JSP Compilation
```

Is this feature also available in RAD 8.0? If so then please tell me where to find it. Additional information can be found [here](http://wisteme.com/question.view?targetAction=viewQuestionTab&id=123).

Comment: Did you find it yet? I'd like to know this option.

Comment: Did you get any answer to this??

Answer (score 1):

This option isn't available anymore on RAD 8.0; as far as I recall, it was gone since RAD 7.5.

However, if what you're looking for is a way to have JSP's precompiled upon deployment, this actually is controlled by the WebSphere extended deployment descriptor. Open up `WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xml` (if it's not there, open up `WEB-INF/web.xml` and select, under "WebSphere Deployment Descriptor": "Open WebSphere Extensions Descriptor"). You will find "Pre-compile JSP's" there.

This setting will be in effect whenever you deploy to your local test environment. If you export the WAR file and deploy on another server, the setting will be in effect as well.